# Wie kann man ins Deutsche das russische Wort проститутка (Prostitutka) in der Bedeutung „verdorbener, verkaufbarer Mensch“ übersetzen?

Tags: translation, meaning

Wie kann man ins Deutsche das russische Wort проститутка (prostitutka) mit der zweiten Bedeutung

> Растленный, продажный, человек  [<sup>Russisches Wörterbuch</sup>](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_fwords/29492/%D0%9F%D0%A0%D0%9E%D0%A1%D0%A2%D0%98%D0%A2%D0%A3%D0%A2%D0%9A%D0%90) (rastlennij, prodazhnij tschelowek)

übersetzen? Wäre es möglich im Deutschen das gleiche Wort zu wählen, das genauso wie im Russischen zwei Bedeutungen hat?

1. weibliche Person, die der Prostitution nachgeht
2. Unter der *zweiten Bedeutung* oben wird ein heuchlerischer Mensch, ein Mensch, der nur sein eigenes Nutzen verfolgt, gemeint, dabei ändert er seine Grundprinzipien abhängig von den herrschenden Grundprinzipien der Gruppe, wo er sich momentan befindet.

Diese Frage kann nur ein Mensch beantworten, der die deutsche Sprache in Wort und Schrift beherrscht. Es geht hier um ein deutsches Homograph und den Homonym zu der gleichen Zeit. Falls es kein deutsches Wort mit zwei Bedeutungen des russischen Wortes gibt, wäre es nett, wenn jemand auf Deutsch mit einem Wort die Bedeutung

> 2) ein heuchlerischer Mensch, ein Mensch, der nur sein eigenes Nutzen
>   verfolgt, gemeint, dabei ändert er seine Grundprinzipien abhängig von
>   den herrschenden Grundprinzipien der Gruppe, wo er sich momentan
>   befindet.

angibt.

Comment: Zu der gleichen Zeit wie was?

Comment: Woher hast Du die Umschreibung 2)? Ich finde sie in keinem Russich-Deutsch-Wörterbuch, und auch nicht _растленный_ aus der russischen Umschreibung. _продажный_ bedeutet hier offenbar _korrupt_ oder _bestechlich_, das passt auch nicht 1:1 zu Deiner deutschen Version von 2).

Comment: @Matthias Das gibt es eigentlich nicht. Der OP hat das nicht aus einem Wörterbuch genommen. Im Russischen Wörterbuch liegt sogar neben der sog. 2. Bedeutung **перен.** (переносное значение), d.h. im übertragenen Sinne, und nicht wie es in der Frage steht (dass das Wort Homograph und Homonym zeitgleich ist -- welches eine unterschiedliche Etymologie verlangen würde, sonst ist die eine Klasse von Worten automatisch eine Teilmenge der anderen Klasse).

Comment: Ich habe die Umschreibung Растленный, продажный, человек aus dem russischen Wörterbuch der Fremdwörter genommen. Wie ich gesehen hatte, hat das deutsche Wort Hure die gleiche Bedeutung wie das russische Wort проститутка. Allerdings gibt es einen Unterschied. Просититутка in ihrer ersten Bedeutung ist eher eine Prostituierte. Das deutsche Wort Hure, wenn ich mich nicht irre, ist eher Шлюха. 
Zu der zweiten Bedeutung, so gibt es einen Ausdruck
Не все политики проститутки, есть и сутенёры. - Nicht alle Politiker sind Huren, es gibt auck Zuhälter [link](http://www.anekdots.com/?id=1692007)

Comment: @CsharpLover Das heißt, die deutsche Version von 2) ist von Dir selbst? Dann glaube ich, dass sie die eigentliche Bedeutung verfälscht. Vermutlich hat user_unkown recht mit seiner Antwort, dass _Hure_ in beiden Bedeutungen als Übersetzung für проститутка verwendbar ist. Aber die Beschreibung unter 2.) passt nicht auf _Hure_. Außerdem: so wie die Frage jetzt nach den Edits da steht, ist sie inkonsistent. Wird nach einem Heuchler gefragt (Text) oder nach einem Korrupten (bzw. "verkaufbar" - Titel)?

Comment: проститутка ist im Russischen neutral. Ich vermute auch, dass Prostituierte im Deutschen auch neutral kling. Allerdings ist шлюха schon nicht so neutral. Ich würde шлюха auf Deutsch als Hure übersetzen. Ich vermute, dass aus diesem Grund das deutsche Wort Hure kaum in der ersten Beudeutung des russischen Wortes проститутка fungieren kann.

Comment: Die 2.Bedeutung des russischen Wortes проститутка im russichen Fremdwörterbuch ist mit den Worten растленный, продажный человек umgeschrieben. Растленный wird als sittenlos, amoralisch übersetzt. Das heisst, dass es nicht nur um einen verkaufbaren sondern auch um einen sittenlosen Menschen geht. Und ein heuchlerischer Mensch und ein sittenloser Mensch sind wie zwei Synonyme. Daher wird in der 2.Bedeutung mit anderen Worten um einen heuchlerischen und gleichzeitig um einen korrupten gefragt

Answer (score 6):

Ja, das Wort Prostituierte, Hure wird auch im Deutschen in dieser übertragenen Bedeutung verwendet, gilt aber als so derb, dass es eher selten verwendet wird.

Auch als Verb, sich prostituieren, ist es durchaus gebräuchlich. Oder X ist eine Hure Ys, etwa "Die Wissenschaft ist eine Hure der Industrie" oder "Die Presse ist eine Hure des Kapitals", "Die Justitz ist eine Hure der Politik" usw.

[Martin Luther](http://www.jesuswahn.de/IDEA-Kubitza-Wick.pdf) soll beispielsweise gesagt haben:

> Die Vernunft ist eine Hure, man muss ihr nur genug bezahlen, dann
>   denkt sie alles, was von ihr gewünscht wird.

[Büchner, Der hessische Landbote](https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Der_Hessische_Landbote):

> Die Justiz ist in Deutschland seit Jahrhunderten die Hure der
>   deutschen Fürsten. Jeden Schritt zu ihr müßt ihr mit Silber pflastern,
>   und mit Armuth und Erniedrigung erkauft ihr ihre Sprüche.

Der Ausdruck

> Das Glück ist eine Hure, jeden Tag bei einem anderen

transportiert aber nur die Unstetigkeit, nicht die Käuflichkeit, die man dem Glück nicht nachsagt.

Eine bemerkenswerte Ausnahme in der Frage, ob der Begriff der Hure/Dirne/Prostituierten als Schimpfwort taugt, stellt dagegen [Karl Kraus](http://www.textlog.de/39079.html) dar.

> Was aber die neue Art des Schimpfens anlangt, so glaube ich nicht, daß
>   man mir in den dreizehn Jahrgängen der Fackel einen Fall wird
>   nachweisen können, wo ich das Wort »Dirne« als Schimpfwort gebraucht
>   hätte und nicht als die Bezeichnung eines erstrebenswerten Zustandes.

Der gesamte Text ist nicht lang, aber zu lang ihn hier komplett zu zitieren.

Comment: "X ist ein Hure Ys" drückt nach meinem Verständnis eine existentielle Notwendigkeit aus: X ist auf das Geld von Y angewiesen, um Existieren zu können; es besteht ein Abhängigkeitsverhältnis, und es geht nahezu immer um Geld. In der Umschreibung des russischen Begriffs lese ich sehr viel mehr Wahlfreiheit, und der "eigene Nutzen" kann vielgestaltiger sein. Außerdem sieht es danach aus, als ob in der gesuchten Bedeutung X Mitglied der Gruppe Y sein soll, was in der Wendung auch nicht gegeben ist.  Deswegen passt _Hure_ für mich nicht gut genug, um sie als Antwort vorzuschlagen.

Comment: Ich denke deine Beispiele von "Hure" sind eher ein Zeichen von (finanzieller) Abhängigkeit, nicht von schlechtem Charakter ("heuchlerischer Mensch"). Eine Hure ist nie Teil einer Gruppe sondern immer Serviceprovider. (Einer Kellnerin würde man ja auch nicht vorwerfen, dass sie Kunden nie widerspricht und zu allen freundlich ist)

Comment: @Matthias: Du meinst Huren & Prostituierte sind nicht das gleiche? Und dass sie in Russland anderen ökonomischen Gesetzen unterliegen als im deutschsprachigen Raum über mehr als 100 Jahre geherrscht haben? Russischen Prostituierten geht es nicht ums Geld? Ich verstehe den Einwand nicht.

Comment: @Iris: Hättest Du den Link zu Kraus gelesen, hätte Dir auffallen können, dass ich mir die Kritik am Charakter von Hurren nicht zu eigen gemacht habe. Allerdings bringt es ihre Dienstleistung mit sich, dass sie heucheln müssen (Liebe, Lust, Verlangen) um dem Freier zu gefallen. Nicht weil sie schlechte Menschen sind, sondern weil sie schlechte Huren wären, wenn sie es nicht täten. Wieso Huren nicht Teil einer Gruppe sein können sollen verstehe ich auch nicht, und was Dienstleistungen damit zu tun haben. Können Friseure auch nicht Teil einer Gruppe sein?  Für mich keine disjunkten Eigenschaften.

Comment: @userunknown Nein, ich meine, dass die Bedeutung 2), rein nach der Umschreibung in der Frage zu urteilen, eine allgemeinere Interpretation des Verhältnisses von X zu Y zulässt, als es durch Hure/Prostituierte ausgedrückt wird. Für mich klingt 2) eher nach Opportunist - aber sich prostituieren und sich opportunistisch verhalten sind mMn zwei verschiedene, wenn auch verwandte Verhaltensweisen. Letztlich beurteilen kann das wohl nur jemand, der gut Russisch kann.

Comment: @Matthias: Soweit ich sehe geht es einmal um Prostituierte/Hure im Wortsinne und das andere Mal schlicht um die Metapher, die damit meist gebildete wird, wobei die Verachtung für Geld oder Sex und Untreue mehr oder weniger im Vordergrund stehen kann. Dass sich CSharpLover auf eine Darstellung der Metapher festlegen musste liegt an der Natur der Sache, sollte uns aber nicht zur Überinterpretation seiner Darstellung ermuntern.

Answer (score 3):

Ein solches Wort ist mir nicht bekannt. Am ehesten käme noch die Wendung "käuflich sein" in Frage, die sich in beide Richtungen interpretieren lässt.

Für die zweite Bedeutung kannst Du [Opportunist](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Opportunist) verwenden. Es betont aber vor allem das Anpassen, weniger das Heucheln.

Comment: _Wendehals_ ginge ugs. für die 2. Bedeutung auch, _Söldner_ seltsamerweise nicht. Daneben fallen mir 2 passende Redewendungen ein: _Wes(sen) Brot ich ess, des(sen) Lied ich sing_ und
_sein Fähnlein / seinen Wimpel nach dem Winde drehen / (auf)hängen_.

Comment: @Crissov, warum geht _Söldner_ nicht?

Comment: @Iris Weiß ich nicht, klingt auf mich aber ungebräuchlich, obwohl es sinngemäß ganz gut zu _käuflich sein_ passt. Es stört lediglich, wie schon Matthias zu _Hure_ im Kommentar auf User Unknowns Antwort bemängelt, dass Söldner ihre Loyalität gegen Bezahlung ändern, Opportunisten und Wendehälse hingegen aus allgemeinerem Eigennutz.

Answer (score 2):

*Nein, das gibt es nicht.*

Das Wort *Prostituierte* ist eine ideale Übersetzung von проститутка in seiner ersten Bedeutung. Dafür besitzt das Wort im Deutschen nur *die* Bedeutung. *Hure, Dirne,* und weitere Nomen, die als Synonyme für *Prostituierte* fungieren, haben die zweite Bedeutung auch nicht.